# ODBC lr_db_dataset_action How write result to file

Tags: loadrunner

I'm trying to write result of function "lr_db_dataset_action" to external file, but now information just write to output log.  I use action Print(Prints the contents of the entire dataset to the Replay Log and other test report summaries).

`lr_db_executeSQLStatement("StepName=SelectQuery", "ConnectionName=bs", "SQLStatement=SELECT C_NUMBER,C_DATE FROM DBS WHERE C_NUMBER3 = {NumIter} - 1", "DatasetName=SetSelect", LAST);`

`lr_db_dataset_action("StepName=PrintDataset", "DatasetName=SetSelect", "Action=PRINT", LAST );`

I think, one of the methods is code(function) on C. Is there another way(built-in function LR)?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are only a few reasons why someone might do this:

- Need to share data output from one virtual user as input to another virtual user
- Test Data creation

Can you please clarify the nature of your need and disclose your efforts with the C file I/O functions?